# teradata database unable to increase database size in permanent space

Tags: teradata

Anyone with teradata database experience? I'm new to this database and I've been tasked to increase the size of a database. I am using Teradata Administrator to do this. I am using `Tools > Modify Database` then increased the size in Perm space.

I'm getting the following error message when trying to modify the database to increase the size:

```
3541: The request to assign new PERMANENT space is invalid
```

My understanding so far is that key is to have enough space in DBC.
The database that I am using is a child database of the parent (DBC).

I can see from running queries that I should have enough size to increase my database since DBC is big enough.

Example:

```
select sum(currentperm) c1, sum (maxperm) c2, c2-c1 from dbc.diskspace;
```

Results:

```
currentperm         maxperm                 c2-c1
293,696,239,616.00  2,382,684,039,413.76    2,088,987,799,797.76
273.525938          2219.047434             1945.521496
```

This tells me I have 1.9TB available in DBC. Am I reading this correctly?
I have plenty of space. So why can't I increase my db?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query and the results don't match, but you're probably right.

This will return the actual available space (modify it accordingly for TBs or 1024**3):

```
SELECT DatabaseName, 
   CAST(SUM(    MaxPerm                  / 1000**3) AS DEC(9,2)) AS MaxPermGB, 
   CAST(SUM(CurrentPerm                  / 1000**3) AS DEC(9,2)) AS CurrentPermGB, 
   CAST(MAX(CurrentPerm) * (HASHAMP()+1) / 1000**3  AS DEC(9,2)) AS SkewedPermGB, -- due to skewed tables
   MaxPermGB - SkewedPermGB AS AvailablePermGB -- this space can be assigned to other databases
FROM dbc.DiskSpaceV
WHERE MaxPerm > 0
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY AvailablePermGB DESC
```

`MODIFY DATABASE` will only work if enough perm is available in the parent/immediate owner. If this database is not in the 2nd level of the hierarchy `dbc` is **not** the direct owner and then it's more complicated. Now you better use `Tools -> Move Space`, but this might fail if you don't have appropriate access rights.

Comment: From looking at the Teradata Administrator tool. I can see that at the root its `DBC > Username1 > Username2 (looks like Username2) is part of Username1 > Database name`. Is this considered level 2 or 3? If 3, what are the steps for `Move Space`?

Comment: @noober: in the first level of the hierarchy there's only `dbc` (the top level). Simply try the  `Move Space` dialog, you specify the sourced and the targetdb for moving space. Actually it will either do a `modify` (if it's a direct owner) or `create database dummydb from sourcedb perm= xxx`, then `GIVE dummydb to target` and a final `drop dummydb`

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Do I need to worry about any other implications with moving? Will this affect permissions, etc? I'm trying to be careful not to break any permissions and access and to keep those intact.

Comment: @noober: No implications, there's `GIVE` but it's on the `dummydb` which is dropped afterwards. This is a standard procedure: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_00/Database_Management/B035_1093_015K/1093Chap9.033.30.html

Comment: Just wanted to confirm. Based on looking at the heirarchy, i can see: `DBC` owns `DBADMIN (U)`, then `DBADMIN` owns `FOO` (U) and then `MYDB (D)` is owned by `FOO`. Is this ok? thx

Comment: @noober: Of course, move the space from `dbc` to `F00`